# PHP Slim Framework request using withAttribute error

Tags: php, slim

I am just try to pass username from middileware auth function

```
$request->withAttribute('username','XXXXXX');
return $next($request, $response);
```

But i cannot access this username using

```
$request->getAttribute('username');
```

I found a solution that its working only when i add like this

```
 return $next($request->withAttribute('username','XXXXXX'), $response);
```

What is the reason? Please help me. I need to pass multiple arguments pass. What should i do?

Comment: I've not used slim before, but observe the state of `$request` object before and after, calling `withAttribute(arg1, arg2)`. possibly $request->withAttribute('foo', 'bar') returns a new object, instead  of changing state of `$request`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`withAttributes` does not change the state of `this` object.

[Excerpt from relevant source code](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Request.php#L930)

```
public function withAttribute($name, $value)
{
    $clone = clone $this; 
    $clone->attributes->set($name, $value);
    return $clone;
}
```

For testing purposes, in your slim fork, change above code as this.

```
/* 
* Slim/Http/Request.php 
*/
public function withAttribute($name, $value)
{

    $this->attributes->set($name, $value);
    return $this;
}
```

Then `return $next($request, $response);` will work as you expected.

[Demo code for inspection](https://eval.in/)

```
<?php 
 /* code taken from - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm*/
 class Book {

      var $price;
      var $title;
      

      function setPrice($par){
         $this->price = $par;
      }
      
      function getPrice(){
         return $this->price;
      }
      
      function setTitle($par){
         $this->title = $par;
      }
      
      function getTitle(){
         return $this->title;
      }
   }
   
    class CopyBook {

      var $price;
      var $title;
      
      function setPrice($par){
         $clone = clone $this;
         $clone->price = $par;
      }
      
      function getPrice(){
         return $this->price;
      }
      
      function setTitle($par){
         $clone = clone $this;
         $clone->title = $par;
      }
      
      function getTitle(){
         return $this->title;
      }
   }
   
   $pp = new Book;
   $pp->setTitle('Perter Pan');
   $pp->setPrice(25);
   
   $cpp = new CopyBook;
   
   $cpp->setTitle('Peter Pan');
   $cpp->setPrice(25);
     
   var_dump($pp);
   var_dump($cpp);
   
   ?>
```

Result:

```
 object(Book)#1 (2) {
  ["price"]=>
  int(25)
  ["title"]=>
  string(10) "Peter Pan"
}
object(CopyBook)#2 (2) {
  ["price"]=>
  NULL
  ["title"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong in so many ways. You should not modify the framework source.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer fails to recognize that Request is immutable, includes a code snippet that clearly demonstrates Request's immutable behavior, links to the source where the DocBlock describes the immutability of Request and the expected behavior of the method, and recommends modifying core framework code (which, by doing, breaks immutability and no longer honors the Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface interface). This is very bad, uninformed, and dangerous advice. Mika Tuupola's answer is correct and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: hey, of course i don't advice to change the framework core. i just wanted to demonstrate how and why things work that way.

Comment: I did not change any framework code. I can understand the situation and change code like this $request = $request->withAttribute('username','xxx');. then  i can add multiple parametrs

Answer (score 6):

Request and Response objects are [immutable](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/value-objects.html#value-objects). This means `withAttribute()` will return a new copy of the `$request` object. You need to return the new object not the original one.

```
$request = $request->withAttribute('username','XXXXXX');
return $next($request, $response);
```